# Tracking tooltip causes grey "trail" of excruciatingly slow repaint

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi, win32gui

Let me first decribe the symptoms of the problem. I'll then give additional facts and explain my question.

## Symptoms

I have written a custom Windows control. The control paints itself in response to a **`WM_PAINT`** message. It also uses **tracking tooltips** (*ie* the tracking feature of the `TOOLTIPS_CLASS` common control).

When I drag the mouse over the control, the tooltip nicely follows the mouse. The **problem** is that it leaves a grey streak in its wake. This streak takes an observable amount of time to repaint -- as you can see from the attached image, I was able to hit PRNTSCRN and take a screenshot of it before the control had time to repaint itself.

[image: Note the grey "trail" where the tooltip once was.]

*(What is even more peculiar is that the `WM_PAINT` handler doesn't appear to have run even once. But note that the code that causes the tooltip to track is in `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, and that is obviously being perfectly responsive.)*

## Facts

- Please assume vanilla C using Win32 libraries.
- The `WM_PAINT` handler is actually very fast. The control has a number of features that require repainting the *entire* client area, and this is imperceptible to the user.

  - Indeed, some features run animations that repaint the whole client area at 15-24fps.
  - It is also decently efficient and doesn't repaint much more than the update rectangle on any given repaint.
- The `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler does nothing and simply returns 1.

  - I never erase the background, I simply paint over it.
- The window has the following style bits set:

  - ws: `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE`
  - ex: `WS_EX_COMPOSITED`
  - cs: `CS_DBLCLKS`
- The parent window is a top-level window with the following style bits set:

  - ws: `WS_TILEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE`
  - ex: `WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE`
  - cs: `CS_REDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS`
- The control's window class background brush is `GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH)`.
- The only other way I have found to cause the same kind of "trail" is by dragging another top-level window over my control. The area that is temporarily obscured by the dragged top-level window leaves the same trail.
- Giving the control's window class the `CS_SAVEBITS` style doesn't seem to make any difference. I still get the same perceptible trail of slow repaints.

## Questions

1. Why am I getting the grey at all, especially if I set `CS_SAVEBITS`?
2. What can I do to make the grey go away?

   - Should I call `UpdateWindow()` each time I move the tooltip?

     - But this doesn't solve the issue of other top-level windows being dragged over top of my control.
   - Help!

Comment: The issue seems to be that the Windows is sending `WM_ERASEBKGND` messages to the parent top-level window without sending any corresponding `WM_PAINT` message to the child control window. If I cripple the paren'ts `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler (by returning 1 without doing anything) the lag-paint problem goes away, but the window background also fails to paint!

How can I make Windows tell the child control to paint!?

Comment: Note: I thought at first the problem was related to [the lagging update region issue described here](http://www.itimdp4.com/winbugs.html) (see the heading "Full Drag"), but that solution didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style bit to the parent window made this issue go away.

For whatever reason, when a window is partly obscured and then revealed, the OS is very generous with the `WM_ERASEBKGND` messages and very stingy with the `WM_PAINT` messages. What was happening is that the parent's `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler was erasing over top of my control. Adding `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` causes the parent window to clip its erasing.

Funnily enough, this solution worked for my control, which simply ignores the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, but didn't work for standard `BUTTON` controls with style `BS_GROUPBOX` style. I expect this is because of the same generous `WM_ERASEBKGND` policy. The standard button control probably dutifully erases its background in handling that message and then vainly waits around for a `WM_PAINT` message.